# All Five letter words with three character repeats?

Tags: python, for-loop

I created 5 for loops that go through each letter in the alphabet and then add those all into a list. I then take that list and for each letter I check if that letter has 3 character repeats and then break. However, this is obviously extremely inefficient and my computer is taking very long to return a result. Does anyone have any better ideas on how I can do this and improve the runtime? 
Examples would be : cccde, yxxxz btw i can't import other libraries other than math, random, string

````
#generate all possible 5 letter combinations without repeats 
    for one in alpha:
        for two in alpha:
            for three in alpha:
                for four in alpha: 
                    for five in alpha:
                        key = str(one+two+three+four+five)
                        if (key in list1) == False:
                            list1.append(key)

    #filter down to ones with three repeated letters:     
    for word in list1:
        for letter in word: 
            if word.count(letter) == 3:
                list2.append(word)
                break```
````

Comment: use `set` and `count`

Comment: I am using count, how would I used set?

Comment: Start by putting your `count` check instead of the list1 `append`. Just check each word generated instead of looping again on a list

Comment: The second set of for loops aren't what's slowing my program down as much, though. For some reason, it's not getting past the first set of 5 loops

Comment: Again, your loops are iterating `11,881,376` times and thus creating a list of that size. That's alot of memory managment that might slow you down. You don't really need `list1`. Check check each `key` if it has 3 letters and add it to `list2` directly

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions?

Comment: Generate all 2-letter sequences. Then insert a `A x 3` string in 1) the beginning of 2-letter sequences, 2) middle of 2-letter sequences 3) end of 2-letter sequences for A being each  one of possible letters.

Comment: @DillonBenson said no imports except `math`, `random`, `string`

Comment: clarification, you say 3 characters repeated but do they need to be sequential? your examples are all sequential but the code would still give positive results for cases like `abaac` etc.

Answer (score 2):

All valid strings only have at most 3 different letters. Either the first is repeated, or the second, or the third. We need some test to prevent that a string that was generated earlier will be added another time:

```py
alpha = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

l = []
for one in alpha:
    for two in alpha:
        for three in alpha:
            l.append(one+one+one+two+three)
            if one != two:
                l.append(one+two+two+two+three)
            if two != three:
                l.append(one+two+three+three+three)
print(len(l), l)
```

If you interpret the question such that the repeated letters don't need to be consecutive, the program probably would change to:

```py
alpha = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
l = []
for one in alpha:
    for two in alpha:
        for three in alpha:
            l.append(one+one+one+two+three)
            if one != two:
                l.append(one + one + two + one + three)
                l.append(one + two + one + one + three)
                l.append(two + one + one + one + three)
                if one != three:
                    l.append(one + one + two + three + one)
                    l.append(one + two + one + three + one)
                    l.append(one + two + three + one + one)
                    l.append(two + one + one + three + one)
                    l.append(two + one + three + one + one)
                    l.append(two + three + one + one + one)
print(len(l))
l = set(l)
print(len(l))
```

This prints two times 165776. Of course just leaving out the duplication tests and converting to a set is simpler, but less fun.

The code can be easily adapted to not allow for 4 or 5 times repeated letters just by having one surrounding if-test to check `one != two and one != three`. In that case there are 162500 solutions.

165776 is also the count of @AlexHall if the code is changed to allow for 3 or four times repetition. And 162500 for the case of exactly 3 repetitions.

For completeness: the case of at least three consecutive letters has 51376 solutions. And the case of exactly three consecutive letters has 50700 solutions.

Comment: This will miss words like `abaca`.

Comment: It depends how you interpret the question. If you also want the non-consecutive repeats, some more variations need to be outputted. And the test for outputting the same string twice becomes trickier.

Comment: Well, given that the problem is that the code in the question is too slow, it is sensible to interpret the question as asking how to do the same thing faster. The code in the question treats words like `abaca` different to `aaabc`.

Comment: What if `one == three`? I think what you need is simply change the list to a set, and then just add all possible arrangements without the checks

Comment: Now it should be better

Answer (score 2):

- Generate all 3-letter strings using `itertools.product` on the alphabet, with a repetition of 3.
- Iterate through those permutations; for each one, triple each letter, giving three different 5-letter solutions.  For instance, from `abc`, you will generate `aaabc`, `abbbc`, and `abccc`.
- Remove the duplicates: 3-letter words with doubled (or tripled) letters will produce duplicates.  For instance, `aab` will generate `aaaab` in two different ways.

Is that enough hint?

Comment: It is almost always inefficient to over-generate and filter.

Comment: question asked no imports and this only makes consecutive repetitions

Comment: The removal of duplicates itself is always going to be inefficient. One can always put the imported code inline to avoid imports.

Comment: @Tomerikoo: ah, so it does.  The edit came after I started my answer, but well before I posted.  `itertools` then gets replaced by the triple-loop.

Comment: @blhsing: Right.  Instead, we would catch this by recognizing consecutive letters as we do the tripling.

Comment: The overhead of "recognizing consecutive letters" is effectively about the same as finding duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with your current algorithm is checking `if (key in list1) == False:`. There is no reason to do that since there would never be any duplicates in your loop and it makes your algorithm O(n^2) instead of O(n) where n is the size of the list. This code runs in reasonable time:

```py
import string

alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
list1 = []

for one in alpha:
    for two in alpha:
        for three in alpha:
            for four in alpha:
                for five in alpha:
                    word = one + two + three + four + five
                    for letter in word:
                        if word.count(letter) == 3:
                            list1.append(word)
                            break

print(len(list1))
```

Comment: This still takes a huge amount of time.

Comment: it is missing a `break` after the `append` line. Each valid word is added 3 times

Comment: @JohanC should be 5 times faster now.

Comment: This version doesn't allow for words with the same letter 4 or 5 times repeated (you can add them with `if word.count(letter) >= 3`).  You can also improve the speed if at the fourth letter you already check that one letter needs to be repeated at least two times.

Comment: @JohanC well, the original code also uses `==` so OP should clarify. Regarding improvements, you could loop `word[:3]` as the last 2 letters will not match anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to pick 2 out of 5 indices to insert non-repeating alphabets into, and use `itertools.permutations` to pick 3 alphabets out of `alpha` for permutations, the first alphabet of which is to be repeated 3 times, and use `itertools.product` to combine the combinations and permutations into one sequence.

Note that since you have edited your question to not allow import of `itertools`, you can simply copy and paste the equivalent code (as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html)) inline to avoid imports.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations, product

output = []
for insert_at, (repeated, *inserted) in product(
        combinations(range(5), 2), permutations(alpha, r=3)):
    output.append(''.join(inserted.pop() if i in insert_at else repeated for i in range(5)))
```

so that given `alpha = 'abcd'`, `output` would become:

```
['cbaaa',
 'dbaaa',
 'bcaaa',
 'dcaaa',
 'bdaaa',
 'cdaaa',
 'cabbb',
 'dabbb',
 'acbbb',
 'dcbbb',
 'adbbb',
 'cdbbb',
 'baccc',
 'daccc',
 'abccc',
 'dbccc',
 'adccc',
 'bdccc',
 'baddd',
 'caddd',
 'abddd',
 'cbddd',
 'acddd',
 'bcddd',
 'cabaa',
 'dabaa',
 'bacaa',
 'dacaa',
 'badaa',
 'cadaa',
 'cbabb',
 'dbabb',
 'abcbb',
 'dbcbb',
 'abdbb',
 'cbdbb',
 'bcacc',
 'dcacc',
 'acbcc',
 'dcbcc',
 'acdcc',
 'bcdcc',
 'bdadd',
 'cdadd',
 'adbdd',
 'cdbdd',
 'adcdd',
 'bdcdd',
 'caaba',
 'daaba',
 'baaca',
 'daaca',
 'baada',
 'caada',
 'cbbab',
 'dbbab',
 'abbcb',
 'dbbcb',
 'abbdb',
 'cbbdb',
 'bccac',
 'dccac',
 'accbc',
 'dccbc',
 'accdc',
 'bccdc',
 'bddad',
 'cddad',
 'addbd',
 'cddbd',
 'addcd',
 'bddcd',
 'caaab',
 'daaab',
 'baaac',
 'daaac',
 'baaad',
 'caaad',
 'cbbba',
 'dbbba',
 'abbbc',
 'dbbbc',
 'abbbd',
 'cbbbd',
 'bccca',
 'dccca',
 'acccb',
 'dcccb',
 'acccd',
 'bcccd',
 'bddda',
 'cddda',
 'adddb',
 'cdddb',
 'adddc',
 'bdddc',
 'acbaa',
 'adbaa',
 'abcaa',
 'adcaa',
 'abdaa',
 'acdaa',
 'bcabb',
 'bdabb',
 'bacbb',
 'bdcbb',
 'badbb',
 'bcdbb',
 'cbacc',
 'cdacc',
 'cabcc',
 'cdbcc',
 'cadcc',
 'cbdcc',
 'dbadd',
 'dcadd',
 'dabdd',
 'dcbdd',
 'dacdd',
 'dbcdd',
 'acaba',
 'adaba',
 'abaca',
 'adaca',
 'abada',
 'acada',
 'bcbab',
 'bdbab',
 'babcb',
 'bdbcb',
 'babdb',
 'bcbdb',
 'cbcac',
 'cdcac',
 'cacbc',
 'cdcbc',
 'cacdc',
 'cbcdc',
 'dbdad',
 'dcdad',
 'dadbd',
 'dcdbd',
 'dadcd',
 'dbdcd',
 'acaab',
 'adaab',
 'abaac',
 'adaac',
 'abaad',
 'acaad',
 'bcbba',
 'bdbba',
 'babbc',
 'bdbbc',
 'babbd',
 'bcbbd',
 'cbcca',
 'cdcca',
 'caccb',
 'cdccb',
 'caccd',
 'cbccd',
 'dbdda',
 'dcdda',
 'daddb',
 'dcddb',
 'daddc',
 'dbddc',
 'aacba',
 'aadba',
 'aabca',
 'aadca',
 'aabda',
 'aacda',
 'bbcab',
 'bbdab',
 'bbacb',
 'bbdcb',
 'bbadb',
 'bbcdb',
 'ccbac',
 'ccdac',
 'ccabc',
 'ccdbc',
 'ccadc',
 'ccbdc',
 'ddbad',
 'ddcad',
 'ddabd',
 'ddcbd',
 'ddacd',
 'ddbcd',
 'aacab',
 'aadab',
 'aabac',
 'aadac',
 'aabad',
 'aacad',
 'bbcba',
 'bbdba',
 'bbabc',
 'bbdbc',
 'bbabd',
 'bbcbd',
 'ccbca',
 'ccdca',
 'ccacb',
 'ccdcb',
 'ccacd',
 'ccbcd',
 'ddbda',
 'ddcda',
 'ddadb',
 'ddcdb',
 'ddadc',
 'ddbdc',
 'aaacb',
 'aaadb',
 'aaabc',
 'aaadc',
 'aaabd',
 'aaacd',
 'bbbca',
 'bbbda',
 'bbbac',
 'bbbdc',
 'bbbad',
 'bbbcd',
 'cccba',
 'cccda',
 'cccab',
 'cccdb',
 'cccad',
 'cccbd',
 'dddba',
 'dddca',
 'dddab',
 'dddcb',
 'dddac',
 'dddbc']
```

Comment: OP states that only allowed imports are `math`, `random` and `string`, i.e. no `itertools`.

Comment: The OP edited the question to disallow imports after I worked on my answer. I've updated my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion with only one for loop, which is reasonably fast on my PC.
First you need cartesian product of 5 set (mathematical set) for creating all 5 letter words with 3 repeated charachters.
After that you can generate all of permutations of these 5 letter words to generate new words.
For cleaning repeated words, you can map the output of previous step to set (deletes the repeated items).

```
from itertools import product, permutations
import string

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
result = []
for repeated in string.ascii_lowercase:
    letters.remove(repeated)

    five_letter_repeated_at_end = product(letters, letters, [repeated], [repeated], [repeated])
    five_letter_words = map(lambda word: set(permutations(word)), five_letter_repeated_at_end)
    current_letter_words = []
    for permutes in five_letter_words:
        permutes = list(map(''.join, permutes))
        current_letter_words.extend(list(permutes))
    result.extend(current_letter_words)

    letters.append(repeated)
print(result)
```

Comment: You are changing the list while looping on it, you don't actually cover all letters...

Comment: OP states that only allowed imports are `math`, `random` and `string`, i.e. no `itertools`.

Comment: Yes, my solution and some other ones missed this part. But I let code remain as same, maybe there is something to learn from!

Answer (score 0):

Beloved `itertools` too (based on Prune's method):

```
from itertools import product, chain
def grow(n):
    '''takes word of three letters and grows another three words'''
    #example: abc -> [aaabc, abbbc, abccc]
    branch1 = n[0]*3+n[1]+n[2]
    branch2 = n[0]+n[1]*3+n[2]
    branch3 = n[0]+n[1]+n[2]*3
    return branch1, branch2, branch3

triple_combinations_generator = product(alpha, repeat=3)
triple_combinations = map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1]+x[2], triple_combinations_generator)
grown_triple_combinations= map(lambda x: grow(x), triple_combinations)
merged_triples = chain(*grown_triple_combinations)
result = set(merged_triples)
print(result)
```

Comment: OP states that only allowed imports are `math`, `random` and `string`, i.e. no `itertools`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an attempt at it with only 4 lines:

```
# Start with set of all letters
s = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'}

# Get all combinations of 5 letters
allcombinations = [(a,b,c,d,e) for a in s for b in s for c in s for d in s for e in s]

# Transform to list
biglist = list(allcombinations)

# Filter for only those that have 3 or more repeats and flatten
result = [a for x in s for a in list(filter(lambda y:y.count(x)==3, biglist))]
```

Here's a timing test (to avoid waiting forever, I've scaled down the number of loops to 3 and matches to 2 in the timing test):

```
# My version
def v1():
    s = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'}
    allcombinations = [(a,b,c) for a in s for b in s for c in s]
    biglist = list(allcombinations)
    result = [a for x in s for a in list(filter(lambda y:y.count(x)==2, biglist))]
    return result

# OP's version
def v2():
    # generate all possible 5 letter combinations without repeats
    alpha = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
         'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
    list1 = []
    for one in alpha:
        for two in alpha:
            for three in alpha:
                key = str(one + two + three)
                if (key in list1) == False:
                    list1.append(key)

    # filter down to ones with three repeated letters:
    list2 = []
    for word in list1:
        for letter in word:
            if word.count(letter) == 2:
                list2.append(word)
                break
    return list2

import time
start_time = time.time()
res1 = v1()
print(f'My version: {len(res1)} entries')
print(f'--- {time.time() - start_time} seconds ---')

start_time = time.time()
res2 = v2()
print(f'OP\'s version: {len(res2)} entries')
print(f'--- {time.time() - start_time} seconds ---')
```

Which outputs:

```
My version: 1950 entries
--- 0.06479763984680176 seconds ---
OP's version: 1950 entries
--- 1.5608229637145996 seconds ---
```

Comment: the fact that it is 4 lines doesn't change the fact that this is still 7 loops. How is that different from the original code? Also `allcombinations` is already a list, no need to re-convert it

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I haven't proposed the fastest algorithm, it's just an attempted cleaner answer. It at least avoids successively appending to lists, which is slow.

Comment: first of all the question asks for a more efficient code. Second, your list-comprehension is adding items to lists. Again, it might not have the explicit word `append` in it, but that is what happening in the background...

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I've edited to flatten my list of lists and you can see that it's much faster than OP's version

Comment: well, remove that unnecessay `if (key in list1) == False:` check and see what happens